# facebook post a youtube video to stream.publish

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the facebook SDK for iOS, but I assume that doesn't matter as every facebook platform has the post option for `stream.publish`

I can send a regular post just fine, but when I post a YouTube video it shows up as a link rather than a YouTube video. Is there a different option other than `stream.publish` I should use to accomplish posting a video?

I tried `video.upload` and `video.publish`, but neither worked. What should I do? ***Thanks.***

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with the C# SDK but it shouldn't be that different.

Are you specifying the post type as a link?
Ex.

```
args["message"] = msg_txt;
args["title"] = title;
args["type"] = "link";
args["link"] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blahblah";
args["source"] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + YouTubeVideoID + "?version=3&rel=0";
```

Can you provide a code snippet of what you are doing?